# Windows app accessing xls data via Interop.Excel library issue

Tags: c#, .net, excel, interop

I have a .NET C# windows app that I need to read some excel data into.  I have started by writing some unit tests .. one of the first just trys to instantiate a Workbook, and it is throwing this error ...

System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: System.Runtime.InteropService.COMException: Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {GUID} failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered {Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG))

This piece of the app is really simple, the one method, 
public Workbook RetrieveWorkbook()
{
     return new Workbook();
}

and one unit test that calls this function.

Code is using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.

I went into the dcom config utility and verified that access seem to be correct.  What am I missing?  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [MSDN Library article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.workbook.workbook%28VS.80%29.aspx) for the Workbook class constructor is quite explicit:

> Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel.Workbook
>   host items cannot be created
>   programmatically.

Use the Application.Workbooks.Add() method, sample code [is here.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173186%28VS.80%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks!!  I was trying to use the Add() first, but could not get past a 'Null reference error' and could not find any useful info on the expected paramaters.  The sample code you provided shows that I don't need any those extra params I was trying to send though .. I will give this way a try.  Thanks!1

Comment: Since I am starting the Excel.Application just a few lines before I try to .Add()the workbook, the workbook collection is always null.  Not sure how the sample code works because I can't get that code to run without a null reference exception.  Not sure what I am missing.

Comment: Let me make sure I understand .. on your machine, when you create a new Application, the Workbooks collection has been initialized?

Answer (score 0):

Like the answer above, the code below works fine:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application xlApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
object o = Type.Missing;
Workbook wkb = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(o);
```